# Algorithm to find best vote based on 5 star

Tags: logic

I need some help in finding best logic for vote system which is based on 5 stars.

Logic is like this:

User has to give rating(5 star rating) for 3 questions for one movie or restaurant

For example :

```
Restaurant name : XYZ

taste : ****** 

price : ***

service : ****
```

How we can findout which is best restaurant?

**case 1**:

Based on total stars (in this case 13)

But,

```
           quest1   quest2  quest3  restaurant
 
user A      4         4       4         AA
user B      5         5       5         BB
user c      1         1       1         AA
```

In this case AA and BB has same vote?

**case 2** :

Average stars (sum of users rating / number of user rated)

```
           quest1   quest2  quest3  restaurant
 
user A      5         5       5         AA
user B      5         5       5         BB
user c      1         1       1         AA
```

In this case, `AA = 18/2`  `BB = 15/1` ?

Any suggestions to get better logic?

Comment: While not directly related to a 5-star system, I found this following link on 'How Not To Sort By Average Rating' quite informative on the subject of rating systems: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: I will add the usual reference to the so-called "bayesian" average, which would help ameliorate your case 2, because it 'gets' the idea that because there's only been one vote cast for B, we can't rely on it as much: http://fulmicoton.com/posts/bayesian_rating/ . Various websites with star ratings use a similar mechanism.

Comment: I got few more examples https://bmark.us/bmark/readable/52c48886743eb6 and http://blog.ekini.net/2013/08/18/getting-the-bayesian-average-for-rankings-mysql/

Comment: Stefun, since it looks like these comments have inspired you to do your own research (great!), and if you found a nice solution, do you want to post an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You will always have ties, so there is no one way to find the best restaurant. For example, 2 restaurants that have all 5 stars.

You could have other data points which support the choice of the restaurant, such as which review was first. The thinking behind this is: the longer a record has been in the system, the more chances it has to have been tested.

You could also have a way to find out which restaurants are the closest to the user and break the tie based on proximity: a 5 star restaurant 1 block away is better than a 5 star restaurant 10 blocks away.

My 2 cents. :)